# Material UI: useStyles (makeStyles) has lower priority after migration to version 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

All my styles started to have lower priority in styles when I migrated to version 5 of Material Ui

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    drawer: {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            width: 0,
        }
    },
    drawerPaper: {
        background: theme.palette.primary.main,
        width: drawerWidth,
    },
}))
```

Answer (score 11):

Based on [official documents](https://mui.com/styles/basics/):

> @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It is
> deprecated in v5. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore.

**NOTE: `@mui/styles` is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.**

Instead of that, you can use [`The sx prop`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) which:

> is a shortcut for defining custom style that has access to the theme.

Or [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/):

> Utility for creating styled components.

Comment: Yeah, it will work, but I am not sure that is the correct way

Comment: @YaroslavShypunov Unfortunately it's a bug in `material-ui 5.0.0` and you can solve it with the given answer.

Comment: =( If it is a bug, I think that they will fix it today.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [tss-react](https://www.tss-react.dev/) rather than other ways when I use [@mui-v5](https://mui.com/).
I've followed a way that makes useStyle priority over [@mui component](https://mui.com/components/) :)
this code works for me, try it out:

```
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { makeStyles } from 'tss-react/mui';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import ThemeProvider from '@mui/material/styles/ThemeProvider';

export const muiCache = createCache({
    key: 'mui', // all material ui classes start with 'css' instead of 'mui' even with this here
    prepend: true,
});

const App = () => {
    return (
        // if you want to use theme, try write that component here, for example:
        // <MyTheme>
            <CacheProvider value={muiCache}>
                <MyApp />
            </CacheProvider>
        // </MyTheme>
    );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles()((theme, props) => ({
    mobileButton: {
        height: 40,
        background: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
}));

const MyTheme = (props) => {
    // const mainTheme = anything...;
    return <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>{props.children}</ThemeProvider>;
};

const MyApp = (props) => {
    const {classes, cx} = useStyles(props);
    return (
        // use cx rather than clsx
        <Button className={cx(classes.mobileButton)}>
            click on me!
        </Button>
    );
};
```