# Material UI makeStyles not changing the css properties of all elements

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

I've copied this exact chunk of code from the documentation after installing `npm install @mui/styles`:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

On my local machine it seems to ignore the color white property, border property as well as the box shadow. Is there a reason for this? I've confirmed in my package.json that im runing mui-material/styles 5.2.3

Comment: I just pasted your code into my own material project and everything seems to be working perfectly fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234190/material-ui-usestyles-makestyles-has-lower-priority-after-migration-to-versio) will answer your question. Because `makeStyles` is deprecated in MUI V5.

You can always use `sx` prop to add custom themes.

I had the same issue and [this article](https://dev.to/atonchev/material-ui-5-the-easiest-way-to-migrate-from-makestyles-to-emotion-1i9l) on dev saved me.